# How to extract classes out of Python modules?

Tags: python, module, import

I'm trying to write a script that takes two Bots and then feeds them to an engine for them to play a game. As an example usage:

```
$:python rungame.py smartbot.py dumbbot.py
Detected SmartBot in smartbot.py...
Detected DumbBot in dumbbot.py...
Running game...
```

The problem I'm having is that I have no idea how to detect/get the Bot objects out of the modules that are provided via the command line. (If it helps any, I wouldn't at all mind enforcing conventions.) How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd probably need the class name as well a module name. With that, you could use this:

```
getattr(__import__(module_name), class_name)
```

If you don't want to make them specify a class name, you might be able to find a class that ends with `Bot`:

```
module = __import__(module_name)
clazz = None
for attribute_name in dir(module):
    attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)
    if attribute_name.endswith('Bot') and callable(attribute):
        clazz = attribute
        break
```

However:

> Explicit is better than implicit. *—[The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)*

So I'd stick with the first approach of letting them specify the module and class name.

Comment: Although probably unrelated to your application, it appears [Werkzeug has some functionality](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.import_string) which can import objects like that, too.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common patterns for this problem is to define in your API that the object must have a particular name;  For instance, you might call that special variable `bot`:

```
# smartbot.py
class SmartBot(object):
    "A very smart bot!"

bot = SmartBot()
```

```
# dumbbot.py
class DumbBot(object):
    "A dumb bot bot!"

bot = DumbBot()
```

```
# rungame.py
import sys
for source in sys.argv[1:]:
    l = {}
    execfile(source, l)
    bot = l["bot"]
    print "Detected %s in %s..." % (type(bot).__name__, source)
print "Running game..."
```